# How can I import a module inside a dialog in angular (8)?

Tags: angular, angular-material, dialog, components, mat-dialog

I have created a dialog as a component to be reused inside my angular project, when I try to import any module inside my dialog the page doesn't work.

The hierarchy of my project:

[image: The hierarchy of my project]

So I imported the dialog-m component inside employee-dash page and it works fine. Then I want to import custom-made module inside dialog-m but it does not work. Although when I import custom-made inside employee-dash it works fine.

Comment: Please share the error messages, i think your poblem is about cirular depencencies

Comment: Is `dialog-m` a module? If so, add `custom-made` module to the import array within `dialog-m`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `dialogs` in itself is a module. If you want to use other components in it, you have to import(export required component as well) the respective module in dilaog module.

Basically, dialog module is unaware of your `custom-made` module.